# Auto discover Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, autodiscovery

I've searched the web and can't find a way to have a *local* Team Foundation Server auto discovered by Visual Studio.

Is it possible to configure it in e.g. Active Directory or the DNS server?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There is no autodiscover feature of TFS similar to that of Exchange. Exchange does [several things to accomplish autodiscover](https://acbrownit.com/2016/01/25/how-does-exchange-autodiscover-work/) and exchange-aware email clients just know where to look. If you're trying to simplify the url you can make a DNS alias so the actual server name is obscured. See [this article on friendly DNS names for TFS](https://edsquared.com/using-friendly-dns-names-in-your-tfs-environment-63014f2817eb)

Comment: I don't want to have to ask around for the TFS Server address every time I use a new Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible.

VS use Team Explorer to connect to TFS, we have to provide the credential to add the TFS server first. The TFS server information is stored with Team Explorer. So, we can do nothing in AD or DNS server.

Once created the connection, the second time to start VS, it will automatically connect to the TFS server.